# How to timeout a read on Java Socket?

Tags: java, sockets, timeout, inputstream

I'm trying to read items from a socket and I notice that if there is nothing on the stream of the socket it will stay at the read and back up my application. I wanted to know if there was a way to set a read timeout or terminate the connection after a certain amount of time of nothing in the socket.

Answer (score 34):

If you write Java, learning to navigate [the API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/overview-summary.html) is helpful. In the case of a socket read, you can [set the timeout option,](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)) e.g.:

```
socket.setSoTimeout(500);
```

This will cause the `InputStream` associated with the socket to throw a `SocketTimeoutException` after a `read()` call blocks for one-half second. It's important to note that `SocketTimeoutException` is unique among exceptions thrown by such `read()` calls, because the socket is still valid; you can continue to use it. The exception is only a mechanism to escape from the read and decide if it's time to do something different.

```
while (true) {
    int n;
    try {
        n = input.read(buffer);
    catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
        /* Test if this action has been cancelled */
        if (Thread.interrupted()) throw new InterruptedIOException();
    }
    /* Handle input... */
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is much better than API documentation. Note how this comes up on google searches rather than the API documentation.

Comment: StackOverflow is a good place to get ideas, but a lot of the information here is sub-optimal or just plain wrong. Relying on what you find here without verifying through primary sources or testing is sloppy.

Answer (score 2):

If this socket was created through a `URLConnection` to perform a web request, you can set the read and connect timeouts directly on the `URLConnection` before reading the stream:

```
InputStream createInputStreamForUriString(String uriString) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    URLConnection in = new URL(uriString).openConnection();
    in.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    in.setReadTimeout(5000);
    in.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    in.setDoInput(true);
    in.setDoOutput(false);
    return in.getInputStream();
}
```

Comment: `setReadTimeout` will only cause an exception, if the timeout elapses *before* the first data is received. After the first data is received, no timeout exception will occur even if the connection hangs infinitely.

Comment: @ooxi That is completely false. The read timeout applies to every read, not just the first one.

Answer (score -5):

Yes, there should be an override of Read() that accepts a timeout value. By 'override' I am not suggesting anyone *write* one, I am pointing out that one of the overrides of the socket methods he is using takes a timeout value.

Comment: And you don't read directly from a socket anyway, you get an `InputStream` from the socket and then read from that.  Do what @erikson says, use `setSoTimeout()`.

Comment: no there shouldn't.  That would make the `SocketInputStream` API different from other streams.  There is already a way to do this that doesn't break the `InputStream` substitutability.