# Stop and wait socket programming with UDP

Tags: java, sockets, udp

Looking to make a Java stop-and-wait UDP server and client but I'm running into some problems starting off. I've made a simple UDP client and server without the stop-and-wait part, but I would now like to learn how to change it. How can I send ACKs and implement timeouts using java sockets ?

Could someone please post up some examples for me to use in my implementation ?

Comment: Please post the important parts of what you have now, and what you're having trouble with. Also, what does `stop-and-wait` mean?

Comment: Stop and wait means that the client sends a message to the server, then times out whilst waiting for an acknowledgement from the server. If all the time expires while its waiting for an acknowledgement the packet is resent, otherwise the next packet is sent

Comment: The stop and wait protocol is the process of sending 1 packet at a time and waiting for the client to send an ack back before sending the next packet.

Comment: You can [set a timeout on sockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570762/how-to-timeout-a-read-on-java-socket)

Comment: Okay, I have called clientSocket.setSoTimeout(1) on my client, so now I want it to check if an ACK has been received, and if it hasn't send the message again...is there some kind of if(ACK RECEIVED) socket method ?

Comment: What do you mean by ACK?  Some special UDP message back?  Or a protocol level ACK?

Comment: Since this is UDP, the receiver will not automatically send you an ack. You will have to do it yourself. So, when the receiver receives the packet, the receiver can send an ack back. You can have two types of packets, a data packet (that is the data you are sending) and an ack packet (that is the ack to the data sent).

Comment: so will I just send back a UDP packet with the bytes containing the string of the sequence no. of the packet or is there a function to send back ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're implementing this in UDP, sending and receiving acknowledgements is up to you. This seems to be what you want for this stop and wait protocol. In terms of pseudocode, you would want something like:

```
int Send(msg)
{
    char rcvBuf[];
    sentBytes = sock.send(msg);
    sock.rcv(rcvBuf);
    return sentBytes;
}

int Recv(rcvBuf)
{
    String ackMsg = "ACK";
    length = sock.rcv(rcvBuf);
    sock.send(ackMsg);
    return length;
}
```

After every send, you wait for an acknowledgement message to come in, and every time you receive, you send an acknowledgement.