# Thread sleep, and continue thread when input is received

Tags: java

I got a problem with my program, when trying to sleep and unsleep a thread.

Right now i'm running 2-threads, the standard thread which checking for input from a TCP device (the two devices are connected), and another thread which handle input from keyboard.

I have a scenario where I will stop one of the thread for 10 sec so it can receive a command.

The code so far:

```
else if ((inputReceived.startsWith("RM20"))) {
    RM20Received = "Yes";
    showMenu();

    display = (inputReceived.substring(2,inputReceived.length()));

    if (scaleInput == null || scaleInput == "B" || scaleInput == "T") {
        System.out.println("Please enter correct RM20 value within 10 seconds");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        if ()
          userValue = scaleInput;
        out.writeBytes("RM20 A " + userValue +"\r\n");
        display = inputReceived;
        showMenu();
        scaleInput = null;
     }

}
```

As you can see, I'm using the `Thread.sleep(10000)`. What I want to the sleep the `Thread`, as I do but "infinite", but as soon as someone enter an input from keyboard, it should keep the thread running after that.

Is there some easy way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, the moderators deleted my answer because I linked to the Java documentation... Use `Socket#setSOTimeout` or a `Future`. It's well explained in the Java documentation.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: no, the moderators did not delete your answer because of the link, but rather because it was only a link and not really an answer. You could edit it, provide more information to make it a more useful and informative answer, and it will likely be re-opened.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels why would I? What is in for me? More negative feedback when it does not get undeleted? Sometimes, a link to documentation *is* a good answer, even when it doesn't fit the companys goals. Instead of complaining and deleting, they could have edited and improved the question themselves, if they don't like links.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: The only reason I saw for your negative feedback was due to your answer being little more than 2 links. If you provided more to your answer, you'd likely get positive feedback and up-votes. But as to your question, `"why would I, What is in [it] for me?"` Why do any of us provide answers here? Perhaps to try to help the original poster solve their problem and to help future visitors solve similar problems. That works for me. Myself, I'm not a threading maven, and so I'll leave it to you and the other threading experts to try to answer this one.

Comment: The point is, you don't need to be a threading expert. You just need to use the provided API for this case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3570776/1060350
And I like keeping my answers short and to the point, which here is: **set a timeout**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to timeout a read on Java Socket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570762/how-to-timeout-a-read-on-java-socket)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 threads, out of which 1 can be used for input. You will have to synchronize the threads so that once the input is received, the waiting thread is notified and it continues its execution

To learn more about synchronization, try this

[Thread Synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an easy way, and that is using old fashion blocking IO. The code you have
posted doesn't cover how you get the input, so I can't be that specific but generally
when you try to read from a stream like a tcp socket or something the user is writing on
stdin the read call will block until data is available. For example, wrapping stdin in a
bufferedReader and the just calling `readLine` will make the thread wait until data is
available before proceeding. If you don't have any specific needs that will be all you
need. No calls to `Thread.sleep` necessary.

If this doesn't help you then you need to be more explicit about exactly what you are
doing to get the input you are waiting for.